# getting error while creating node js express app project

Tags: node.js, windows, webstorm

I am getting the following error when I try to create a new project for nodejs express app -

```
Create Express Project
        Error creating Node.js Express App. Failed command:
        "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install
        Exit code: -1
```

I am using webstorm.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "untitled4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.3.3",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it that you are facing an installation issue or is it when you are running an app? Can you give more details

Comment: No, i have installed webstorm succesfully but when i try to create a new project for node.js express app I get this error

Comment: Do you have `node.js` and `npm` installed on your machine?

Comment: i installed node.js from internet but i never installed npm. should i install it?

Comment: Then it looks as if the express is not properly installed. Else can you please paste your code snippet and your package.json?

Comment: apparently this looks like an installation issue. I spent an hour trying replicate this. NPM comes by default when you install node. Express and others have to be installed as `npm install express` . I hope you did not copy the contents of `package.json`. Try reinstalling Node and express and other libraries that you have referenced in your code. Let us know the result.

Comment: please try running 'npm install express' in cmd console - cd to you project directory and run the command there. What is the result?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the cause was the project folder name; it was `xxxx xxxx`. The fix was removing the space from project name, so I changed it to `xxxx_xxxx`.